# How to format excel generated graph delimiter in word

Tags: excel, ms-word, excel-formula, string-formatting

I have copy pasted a graph from excel to word

It puts `,` as delimiter but i want it to put `.` as delimiter

Here i show what i mean
[image]

Answer (score 0):

If changing the comma to a period in the Format Code field on the bottom right doesn't do it for you, my first thought is that this may have something to do with your system settings rather than something in the application? Is your machine set to a European region perhaps?

I'm assuming that the chart displays the way you want it in Excel? If so, then you could always do a screen grab and paste the image into Word...

Comment: yes my computer is set to Turkish , Turkey. In excel i am able to change it from advanced settings but there is no option in word :( in excel i change use system seperators

Comment: Yeah, Excel is much better at working with numbers and formatting them in different ways, Word is really just for text. There might still be a way to do it in the application settings (File>Options), though I'm not at my computer right now so I can't check...